# Avoid floating point operations in C

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, stm32

I am working in an embedded STM32F4 project and as a constraint i can only use integers.

I have already a working solution using floats.

```
#define TIMER_PERIOD 0.0000020833

float Get_Speed_Period(){
    int tics = Get_Timer_Tics();
    return tics * TIMER_PERIOD;
}

float Get_Rotation_Speed(float speed_period){
    return (1 / speed_period * 64);
}

int main(){
    float W = Get_Rotation_Speed ( Get_Speed_Period() );
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to only use integers. How can I achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the algebra to find `W` as a function of `tics` without the intermediate steps.

Comment: If you are after correct rounding you might add half of the divisor to the dividend before dividing.

Comment: [Fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) may help.

Comment: You get more precise results if you delay divisions as late as possible: `64/speed_period` is `64/(tics/48001)` or (rounding issues ignored) `48001*64/tics` or, if rounding applied: `(48001*64 + tics/2)/tics`. Note how `64*40081` turns into a constant, too...

Comment: Pretty sure that 0.000020833 is just a truncated version of 0.000020833333333... so the reciprocal is 48000, not 48001.

Comment: @user3386109 You are correct!

Comment: @Charles34 STM32F4 - it has FPU. Why do not use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick note: you may wish to use a `long long` datatype for a higher storage capacity (typically 8 bytes) depending on the size of the resulting integers you're calculating.

But if you use the functions the way you are, you are losing some of the optimizations you can make math-wise.  Functionally you're doing this:

```
W = (1/(tics * timerperiod) * 64)
```

And if you simplify that math (note that your 64 ends up in the numerator -- if that's not what you wanted, then you need to reframe this some), you get:

```
W = 64 * (1/timerperiod) / tics
1/timerperiod = 1/0.000020833 = 4800.7680
W = 64 * 48000.7680 / tics
W = 64 * 48000.7680 / Get_Timer_Tics();
```

So then you can implement it using mostly integers:

```
long long W = 64 * 48000 / Get_Timer_Tics();
```

Note that I rounded the 48000 down since I suspect the original value was not 48001 and floating point math made it off by a bit.

Comment: I don't see the need for a `long long` integer to contain the result. As long as `Get_Timer_Tics()` is non-zero (a condition that should really be checked for), the maximum value of W is just 307200, which an ordinary `int` can handle quite easily.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm facing some precision issues... For instance: expected value was 3750 and got 3840... How can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: @Charles34 I suspect you wrote the formula a bit differently, like `48000 / Get_Timer_Tics() * 64`, perhaps? In C, multiplication and division are performed left to right, so what you're probably doing is calculating `48000 / Get_Timer_Tics()`, then multiplying this (integer) result by 64. It might help to add brackets to your code, e.g., `W = (64 * 48000) / Get_Timer_Tics()`, or for proper rounding, `int t = Get_Timer_Tics(); W = (64 * 48000 + t/2) / t;`

Comment: @r3mainer: agreed, I said "if" they get large -- depends on the environment and I didn't want to assume Get_Timer_Tics() was small

Comment: @r3mainer and @Charles34 -- What r3mainer said is what I was worried about too.  I'm not sure if the original 64 in your code was supposed to be in the bottom of the fraction or not.  IE, what you wrote was `(1 / speed_period * 64)` which is really `64 / speed_period`.  If you wanted it on the bottom, you need to use `()`s: `(1/(speed_period * 64))`

Comment: @Charles34 You should post a new question with your current code to address that issue.  Include your results and indicate expected and actual, and why you expect the result.  For example how do you know 3750 is the expected answer?